# How can I pass arguments to a script from C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ssh.net

I'm using SSH.NEt library to connect to a Linux Box. I can execute a normal script which doesn't require any arguments. But I'm not sure How to pass arguments to the scripts using "RunCommand" option.

```
SshClient ssh = new SshClient(host, user, pass);
ssh.Connect();
bool conn = ssh.IsConnected;
var cmd = ssh.RunCommand("/bin/script.pl");
var result = cmd.Result;
ssh.Disconnect();
ssh.Dispose();
```

The "script.pl" files need arguments to run. Where Exactlu can I pass the argument in the code to run this script.

Comment: Did you check the docs? Anyone who is going to answer is going to look up the documentation

Comment: @Santi this question is about SSH, not cmd

Comment: have you tried `ssh.RunCommand("/bin/script.pl param_1 param_2... param_n");`?

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @Gusman Yes I tried that but It keeps giving me an error that /bin/ is a directory. cant execute.

Comment: can you post the exact command you tried with parameters? It should work, it may be just a matter of surrounding the parameters with quotes.

Comment: ssh.RunCommand(@"/u/bin/script.pl src1 src2 1 id");

It takes 4 arguments.